# Can I make MySQL SELECT LIKE syntax smarter?

Tags: mysql

I've noticed that LIKE 'a%' would return results with 'árbol' but LIKE 'AE%' will not return results like "Æther". What is the extent to which LIKE is smart? Lets say I have these database entries:

```
Black Blue
Black Blew
```

Is there any way to have MySQL match both smartly with LIKE 'Black Bleu' (Since they are quite close)? Or is LIKE '_%' only capable of matching exact characters, with the aforementioned exception?

Comment: Æ is one character, AE is two.

Comment: @muratgu If you were searching for it, though, many might type "AE".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL's fulltext searching is pretty limited, as it's a database, not a search engine.

You should look into something like [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which supports all sorts of things like "sounds like" matching, stemming (i.e. "smarter" and "smart" are the same), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use SOUNDEX's or the SOUNDS LIKE operator

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

```
mysql> SELECT SOUNDEX('Blue'), SOUNDEX('Blew'), SOUNDEX('Blue') = SOUNDEX('Blew');
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
| SOUNDEX('Blue') | SOUNDEX('Blew') | SOUNDEX('Blue') = SOUNDEX('Blew') |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
| B400            | B400            |                                 1 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MySQL, but on SQL Server, regex is your friend

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field LIKE 'Black Bl[e|u]%'
```

Assuming that you're looking to match the 'similar' spellings, rather than on the fact that the two words sound the same :)

Comment: I think he's looking to improve overall arbitrary search functionality, not get a single query to work better...